# Simple regex issues

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help and explanation (if possible) with one regex.
Here are the specifications:

- It is surrounded by 2 characters, either "::" or "**" (only two and they must match at the start and the end of the word )
- It is at least 3 characters long (without the surrounding symbols)
- It starts with a capital letter
- Continues with lowercase letters only

Here is my regex:

```
([*|:]{2})(?<emoji>[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,})\1
```

here is the test input

```
Test, test  test::Heart:::::: This includes 3 **Snake**, 1 ::Elephant:, 12 **Monk3ys**, a **Gorilla::, 5 ::fox:es: and 21 different types of :Snak::Es::. ::::::::Moon:: **Shy****
```

**Shy**

My regex is wrongly matching `Elephant`, `Moon` and `Shy` because these words have more than 2 (`:` or `*`).

I've tried with (`^` and `$`) for start and end of the string but with no success.

Comment: What should be the match in `*::Heart::*`

Comment: In this example nothing must be matches because the first symbols are more than 2 and are not the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain that? How would it be for `!::Heart::!` Or any other surrounding characters? Like comma? `::Heart::,` or `"::Heart::"` (with quotes)... etc. Can you be specific?

Comment: It's not a "simple" regex issue :p it's serious.

Comment: @trincot, its edited, it should not match any of these you've mentioned.

Comment: What *should* be the match in the example string? Your pattern is not matching `Elephant` right?  https://regex101.com/r/ODrquw/1

Comment: But can you be specific about **which** characters are allowed around a potential match? If you say these are not acceptable, then why do you expect `**Snake**` to match, since it is immediately followed by a comma? Isn't the comma a problem? Please define exactly which character is allowed to surround a potential match and which not.

Comment: Only two :: or two ** are allowed. And they must match so ::Girls** should not be matched, and **Girls** should be matched.

Comment: So if **nothing** else is allowed then you are actually saying there cannot be anything else in the input. Why then do you give an example with many words?

Comment: should `::Heart::*` be matched? what of `*::Heart::*`?

Comment: Does `hello ::There::, bye` have a match? Does `hello ::There::!` have a match? Does `hello !::There::` have a match?

Comment: So there should be nothing surrounding the match?  Like `(?<!\S)([*:])\1[A-Z][a-z]{2,}\1\1(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/3QBsBc/1 Should there be a match in your original example string?

Comment: Yes, the match should work ONLY if nothing is surrounding the match except of the allowed characters.

Comment: So then trivially nothing should match in the example you have given because then the input should necessarily only consist of one word only (with the delimiters around it). I actually think there is a big misunderstanding here, and I hope you can clarify by editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that your regex does not prevent matching strings that have more than twice the delimiter (like three `:::`), there are also some other issues:

- `[*|:]` also matches a pipe symbol.
- `[*|:]{2}` may match a pair of two *different* symbols

I would actually capture only one occurrence of the delimiter, like `([*:])`, and then use `\1` multiple times to match the repetition of that *same* character.

You could use look-around assertions to reject when there are more delimiting symbols than the 2 that are required.

```
(?<![*:])([*:])\1(?<emoji>[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,})\1\1(?![*:])
```

If there are other symbols you don't want to have immediately before/after the delimiters, then add them to the negative look around assertions.

If you don't want **anything** surrounding the delimited word, then you should test that the input is only that, using `^` and `$`:

```
^([*:])\1(?<emoji>[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,})\1\1$
```